# In java string length != 0 or string length >0 which is better and faster way to check string have some value in it?

Tags: java, string

To check whether a string has some values in it we can do:

```
string.length() != 0
```

or

```
string.length() > 0
```

(String length can not be negative in Java).

So which is the better programming style to check this?

Also which is faster?

Comment: `String#isEmpty` or `String#trim#isEmpty()` if you want to ignore white spaces....I don't think any are faster as each has to check the `length` value (or in the case of `isEmpty` incur a method call)

Comment: Also this is known as micro-optimization. When you worry about "which one is a faster way to check for non-empty String", it means you're really wasting your time on irrelevant things.

Comment: You should be thinking about what is clearer and only worry about performance when you have measured you have an issue.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use the [`String#isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) method. It was meant for this exact purpose.

**P.S:** If the string contains `space`, it'll not be an empty String. You need to `trim` the String in that case, before checking for `isEmpty`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `StringUtils.isBlank("String")` from Apache Commons Lang.
It's easy and returns true if the string is empty or contains only blancs.

Answer (score 1):

The chances are that testing using `>` or `!=` is going to take exactly the same time.  If there is difference in performance, then the chances are:

- it will be too small to be significant to application performance,
- it will depend on the larger context of the program, and
- it will vary (or disappear) depending on the hardware platform and/or the version/release of Java that you are using.

My advice would be to focus on making your application work, making it reliable and making it maintainable.  Even *thinking* about performance at this level is probably a waste of your time for the vast majority of applications ... Java or otherwise.

I agree with @R.J.'s suggestion of using `String.isEmpty()`, and leave it to the Java implementors to implement this operation efficiently.